# How to get layer for a given feature

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

How does one get the layer for a given feature? When a user selects a feature on the map I need to access some layer properties. In ol2 I used feature.layer.

Comment: Also see this open PR for the select interaction: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3454

Answer (score 3):

For now, it's not possible to walk from the feature to the layer but you can create a workaround like:

```
ol.Feature.prototype.getLayer = function() {
    var this_ = this, layer_;
    var sameFeature = function(feature){
        return (this_ === feature) ? true : false;
    };
    map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer){
        var source = layer.getSource();
        if(source instanceof ol.source.Vector){
            var features = source.getFeatures();
            if(features.length > 0){
                var found = features.some(sameFeature);
                if(found){
                    layer_ = layer;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return layer_;
};
```

And then use like:

```
var layer = feature.getLayer();
```

Comment: It should be noted that a feature might be in several sources, or none.

Comment: Also, a significant optimization would be to use the getFeatureByID method of the source if the feature has an id.

Comment: @AlvinLindstam you're right but the question is about a reverse traversing, so the source is unknown.